# Using more number of relational database in django

Tags: django, django-models

Using more number of `ForeignKey's` in Django cause any problem in production? Is there any limits of using `models`. I'm using cache to handle some views.But I'm really worried about my database design.

In my project, I'm using 30 FK's to store information about users and activities.right now all working fine on the production server.In future, more FK will present.Using more number DB's cause any problem in future?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is not really a limit on the use of models/tables/foreign keys/relations, that's where database are for: handling big loads of data. The way you handle your database operations are of more importance here.

In combination with Django: this is the best book I know to explain it all to you with nice and ably examples.

https://www.twoscoopspress.com/products/two-scoops-of-django-1-11